# Como colocar um subtítulo embaixo no nome do aplicativo no menu bar

Tags: android

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou querendo colocar duas coisas no menu bar, mais não faço ideia de como faz isso.
O WhatsApp tem duas coisas no menu bar, o nome do contato e a hora que visualizou o WhatsApp.

Tem como eu fazer isso? Ter dois nomes no menu bar?

**Minha classe  MainActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ViewPager galeria = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.galeria);
    GaleriaImagensAdapter adapter = null;
    try {
        adapter = new GaleriaImagensAdapter(this);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    galeria.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Aí lá na hora de setar a imagem eu tava querendo trocar o título e subtítulo, usando este setTitle e setSubtitle, tem como?

**Aqui eu coloco a imagem**

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup pager, int position) {
    ImageView imagem = new ImageView(context);
    imagem.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

    try {
        Class res = R.drawable.class;
        Field field = res.getField(itens.get(position).nome_foto);
        int drawableId = field.getInt(null);
        imagem.setImageResource(drawableId);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MyTag", "Failure to get drawable id.", e);
    }
    ((ViewPager) pager).addView(imagem, 0);
    return imagem;
}
```

Comment: Com "wpp" você quis dizer "WhatsApp"?

Comment: A `ActionBar` possui um *setTitle* e *setSubtitle*. É isso que você se refere?

Comment: Eu estou querendo fazer isso da imagem , mais não sei como. Este setSubtitle deve funcionar. como eu uso?


Luidne e sim , mania de abreviar

Comment: Bom, o que tem no WhatsApp é diferente do que você mostrou na imagem. O WhatsApp utiliza a `ActionBar` do Android com um título e subtítulo, o que é simples. Este da imagem é algo ainda mais personalizado.

Comment: a imagem e para ilustrar , só preciso de ter estas duas informações

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso você deve registrar um `listener` para quando o item do `ViewPager` mudar você capturar o evento e fazer algo relacionado.

Isso pode ser feito assim:

```
ViewPager galeria = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.galeria);
galeria.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        getActionBar().setTitle("Posição "+position);
        getActionBar().setSubtitle("Posição "+position);

        // Para biblioteca de compatibilidade
        //getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Posição "+position);
        //getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Posição "+position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});
```

Para alterar conforme o item do *adapter* você também pode criar um método que busque-o passando a posição recebida no `onPageSelected()` e então, alterar seu título e subtítulo imediatamente.

Comment: Tem como centralizar o texto?

Comment: Tem sim, dê uma olhada nessa resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26548766/3618148

Answer (score 1):

Na sua `Activity`, utilize o código abaixo para definir o título e subtítulo, caso você esteja utilizando [`ActionBar`](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html):

```
getActionBar.setTitle("Título");
getActionBar.setSubtitle("Subtítulo");
```

Ou `getSupportActionBar` caso esteja utilizando a biblioteca de compatibilidade.